# Angular Date pipe month value wrong

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I have the following code in my template:

```
<div>{{createdOn | date:'yyyy-mm-dd'}}</div>
```

The value of `createdOn` is `1565762489936` in milliseconds. In terms of date it is 'Wed 14 August 2019'.

Instead I get '2019-31-14'. The month value is wrong.

Whats the issue here?

Comment: `mm` should be minute, use `MM` instead for month. See also: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Thanks a ton for input and link.Worked perfectly. Add it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Angular’s Date Pipe you need to keep its [custom format options](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options) in mind:

Lowercase `mm` will print the minute with two digits.

What you should use instead is uppercase `MM` which represents the month:

```
<div>{{createdOn | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#description) we can custom month as follows,
[image]

So in your case simple `mm` should be capital